# Почему функциональное выражение возвращает NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

**Данный код возвращает NaN, почему** ? *такое чувство, что я знаю, но не могу вспомнить* =D

```js
let sum = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(sum(5 + 4));
```

Answer (score 7):

функция `sum` принимает два аргумента.

Передается ей, всего один: `5+4`, что равносильно вызову `sum(5 + 4, undefined)` → `sum(9, undefined)`

Внутри функции происходит сложение числа и `undefined`, как результат - `NaN`